# Trigger function when element is visible on screen (viewport)

Tags: angular, scroll, viewport

jQuery has the plugin [appear](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear) or waypoint to detect if element is visible or not in viewport. I did some research, I can not find and wonder if Angular2 has a similar plugin.
If not yet, what is the best way to do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

`sync-dom.utils.ts`

```
static isInViewPort(rect: ClientRect, threshold = 0) {
    return rect &&
        rect.height &&
        rect.top + rect.height + threshold >= 0 &&
        rect.left + rect.width + threshold >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom - rect.height - threshold <= SyncDomUtils.windowHeight &&
        rect.right - rect.width - threshold <= SyncDomUtils.windowWidth;
}
```

`dom.utils.ts`

```
async isInViewPort(rect: ClientRect) {
    return SyncDomUtils.isInViewPort(rect);
}
```

and in your component you do:

```
async isInViewPort() {
    // you have to import the Renderer and ElementRef from angular/core
    this.boundingRect = await this.domElementUtils
        .invokeElementMethod(this.renderer, this.el.nativeElement, 'getBoundingClientRect');

    return await this.domUtils.isInViewPort(this.boundingRect);
}
```

and use that function as this.isInViewPort() and it will return a boolean

this is the `invokeElementMethod` I have in a `dom-element.utils.ts`

```
async invokeElementMethod<T extends keyof HTMLElement>(renderer: Renderer, element: any, methodName: T, args?: any[]) {
    return await renderer.invokeElementMethod(element, methodName, args) as any;
}
```