# Angular 5.2.0: Optimize large list rendering

Tags: angular, optimization

I'm working on an Angular 5.2.0 application and ran into an issue I can't seem to solve.
The problem lies in the rendering of a potentially large array of objects (each containing an array of other objects).
Basically, it can be seen as such :

```
interface B {name: '', value: '', ... }
interface A {name: '', nested: B[], ...}
```

Unfortunatly, with the way I do things for now, this generates a huge number of DOM nodes and slow down massively my application.

---

So far, I've tried to solve my rendering issue using [this virtual scroller package](https://github.com/rintoj/ngx-virtual-scroller) but to no avail.

I tried to limit the displayed nodes to what was in the viewport based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43673986/trigger-function-when-element-is-visible-on-screen-viewport), but the browser computation went crazy.

I went and look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37600154/how-can-i-speed-up-ngfor-for-a-large-array) which seemed promising but couldn't adapt it to my app.
In this question, there was a mention of [cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview) which looks good but is Angular7 specific.

---

As for the code, it can be dumbed down to the following

```
<!-- Template -->
<div *ngFor="let o of obj">
<div class="a">
        {{o.name}}
    <div class="b" *ngFor="let b of o.nested">
        <div>{{b.name}}</div>
    <div>{{b.value}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

with a potentially large `obj` and a potentially large `nested` for each `obj` (let's say for example `obj.length` is 500 and `obj[0].nested.length` is 200).

All that while this list is displayed at all times and the values are refreshed periodically (so a redraw is quite inevitable).

---

It would really help me if you could direct me towards a solution (preferably not involving an upgrade to Angular 7 ) that could either partially display this list while being able to scroll relatively fast or avoid this ugly double ngFor loop (I can't do much about the data, I'm afraid).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using OnPush `ChangeDetectionStrategy`

Comment: I advise watching this presentation to see some techniques for optimizing an Angular application https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybNj-id0kjY&ab_channel=ng-conf

Comment: @CornelC Yes, my component's detection strategy is `OnPush`. There was a slight improvement from the standard detection strategy, but not enough.

Comment: @Askirkela Are the objects created from scratch every time? I think Angular can reuse already rendered DOM nodes when the objects on which they are based are the same (meaning *the same objects*, not just having the same content).